# Using "Interop.Word" DLL Repeating the paragraph in the document below the old paragraph

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` DLL i want to find the particular Paragraph and repeat that paragraph in the document below the old paragraph. Here i'm able to to extract the paragraph from the selected document using given `string (or) text`.

Below is the code block:

```
    private string[] ReadFileContent(Document doc, string Key)
    {                               
       Word::Application WordApp;
       WordApp = new Word.Application();
        List<string> SelectedParagraphs = new List<string>();
        string parac = string.Empty;
        for (int j = 1; j <= doc.Paragraphs.Count; j++) //numeration of paragraphs starts from 1
        {                                
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para = doc.Content.Paragraphs[j];
            int cSent = para.Range.Sentences.Count;
            string a;
            for (int l = 1; l <= cSent; l++)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range sent = para.Range.Sentences[l];
                a = sent.Text.ToString();
                if (a.IndexOf(Key)>-1)
                {
                    parac = parac+ "," + j.ToString(); 
                }
            }
        }
        parac = parac.TrimStart(',');
        string[] ParaArray = parac.Split(',');
        string[] Result = new string[ParaArray.Count()];

        for (int m = 0; m < ParaArray.Count(); m++)
        {
            int i = 0;
          //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraphs DocPar = doc.Paragraphs;
            // Count number of paragraphs in the file
            long parCount = DocPar.Count;
            // Step through the paragraphs
            int paraGraphNum = Convert.ToInt32(ParaArray[m]);

            while (i < parCount)
            {
                i++;
                if (i == paraGraphNum)
                {
                   // sb.Append(DocPar[i].Range.Text);
                    Result[m] = DocPar[i].Range.Text;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @JohnSaunders  we are developing desktop application only not Server technology, i am very familiar server side coding rather than desktop application thats why i choose ASP.net. we are at the stage of doing R&D only.

Comment: Ok, here's the result of the research: don't do it. Do not try to run Office Interop in a server application. Use a tool such as Aspose Word, which is _made_ to run in a server application.